# Android Activity: Handle Intent after onCreate()?

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-activity

I have a problem with the order in which my Android Activity is intitialized.

**Basics:**

The Activity contains a ViewPager with contains 3 Fragments. The Activity is opened this way:

```
  Intent foodsActivityIntent = new Intent(getActivity(), FoodsActivity.class);
  foodsActivityIntent.putExtra("NavigationPosition", navigationPosition);
  foodsActivityIntent.putExtra("SearchQuery", searchQuery);
  foodsActivityIntent.putExtra("SelectedDateMillis", _currentDay.toDate().getTime());

  startActivityForResult(foodsActivityIntent, 200);
```

In the onCreate - Method i catch the Intent and do some stuff:

```
  Intent intent = getIntent();
  if (intent != null) {
    //Some stuff
      _foodsPagerAdapter.performSearch();
  }
```

The interesting part here is "_foodsPagerAdapter.performSearch()". With this i want to perform a search in each Fragment.

```
public void performSearch() {
    if (_foodSearchFragment != null)
        _foodSearchFragment.performSearch();
    if (_foodFavoritesFragment != null)
        _foodFavoritesFragment.performSearch();
    if (_foodCustomFragment != null)
        _foodCustomFragment.performSearch();
}
```

**The Problem:**

As you can see, the search method in each Fragment is only called if the Fragment is not null. My problem is that the getItem() - Method(which initializes the Fragments in the Adapter) is called after the onCreate (and onStart) Method finished. So the performSearch - Method for each Fragment is never called.

You can understand this better with this Logcat output:

[image]

First performSearch is called and then getItem(). But getItem must be called first for my code to work.

getItem():

```
@Override
public Fragment getItem(int i) {

    Log.i("FoodActivityTest", "call getItem in FragmentPagerAdapter");

    Fragment fragment = null;

    switch (i) {
        case 0:

            if (_foodSearchFragment == null)
                _foodSearchFragment = new FoodSearchFragment();

            fragment = _foodSearchFragment;
            break;
        case 1:

            if (_foodFavoritesFragment == null)
                _foodFavoritesFragment = new FoodFavoritesFragment();

            fragment = _foodFavoritesFragment;
            break;
        case 2:

            if (_foodCustomFragment == null)
                _foodCustomFragment = new FoodCustomFragment();

            fragment = _foodCustomFragment;
            break;
    }

    return fragment;
}
```

What am I doing wrong? Do I need to approach the problem differently?

**EDIT 1:**

FoodsActivity:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_foods);

    //Init some views

    _viewPager = findViewById(R.id.viewpager_foods);
    _foodsPagerAdapter = new FoodsPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager(), this);
    _viewPager.setAdapter(_foodsPagerAdapter);

    handleOpenIntent();

    //do more stuff (show ads etc.)

    Log.i("FoodActivityTest", "onCreate finished");
}

@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();

    Log.i("FoodActivityTest", "onStart finished");
}



private void handleOpenIntent() {


    Intent intent = getIntent();
    if (intent != null) {
        int navigationPosition = intent.getExtras().getInt("NavigationPosition");
        String searchQuery = intent.getExtras().getString("SearchQuery");

        _viewPager.setCurrentItem(navigationPosition);

        _foodsPagerAdapter.performSearch(searchQuery);
    }

}
```

**EDIT 2:**

FoodsPagerAdapter:

```
public class FoodsPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
private Context _context;
private FoodSearchFragment _foodSearchFragment;
private FoodFavoritesFragment _foodFavoritesFragment;
private FoodCustomFragment _foodCustomFragment;

public FoodsPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm, Context context) {
    super(fm);

    _context = context;
}

@Override
public Fragment getItem(int i) {

    Log.i("FoodActivityTest", "call getItem in FragmentPagerAdapter");

    Fragment fragment = null;

    switch (i) {
        case 0:

            if (_foodSearchFragment == null)
                _foodSearchFragment = new FoodSearchFragment();

            fragment = _foodSearchFragment;
            break;
        case 1:

            if (_foodFavoritesFragment == null)
                _foodFavoritesFragment = new FoodFavoritesFragment();

            fragment = _foodFavoritesFragment;
            break;
        case 2:

            if (_foodCustomFragment == null)
                _foodCustomFragment = new FoodCustomFragment();

            fragment = _foodCustomFragment;
            break;
    }

    return fragment;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return 3;
}

@Override
public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {

    switch (position) {
        case 0:
            return _context.getString(R.string.activity_foods_search);
        case 1:
            return _context.getString(R.string.activity_foods_favorites);
        case 2:
            return _context.getString(R.string.activity_foods_customfood);
        default:
            return "Error";
    }
}

public void performSearch(String query) {

    Log.i("FoodActivityTest", "call performSearch");

    if (_foodSearchFragment != null)
        _foodSearchFragment.performSearch(query);
    if (_foodFavoritesFragment != null)
        _foodFavoritesFragment.performSearch(query);
    if (_foodCustomFragment != null)
        _foodCustomFragment.performSearch(query);
}
```

Comment: Can you provide your whole FoodActivity.class?

Comment: I have added it in a simplified form. So what I think is relevant.

Comment: I think i found a solution. But dont know if it is a good solution. Feels dirty, but seems to work:    _viewPager.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
      _foodsPagerAdapter.performSearch(searchQuery);
                    }
                }, 500);

Comment: full code of `adapter` required to understand the issue

Comment: I have added the adapter code

Comment: Rather than calling `fragment.performSearch()` from your activity's `onCreate()` method, could you just call `performSearch()` from your _fragment's_ `onViewCreated()` method?

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to pull the values out of your intent before you initialize the other objects.  From the looks of it currently, you are trying to populate an view with no data, then assign the data later.  To solve, you could either better handle the null in your adapter, or move your data assignment.  I would probably do the latter.

```java
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_foods);

// Added this.  Moved part of handleOpenIntent() here, other half is below view init.
    String searchQuery = "";
    Intent intent = getIntent();
    if (intent != null) {
        int navigationPosition = intent.getExtras().getInt("NavigationPosition");
        searchQuery = intent.getExtras().getString("SearchQuery");
    //should probably have some error handling if the SearchQuery is missing or the value is invalid.
    }
// End of additions

    //Init some views
    _viewPager = findViewById(R.id.viewpager_foods);
    _foodsPagerAdapter = new FoodsPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager(), this);
    _viewPager.setAdapter(_foodsPagerAdapter);

// added this too, moved out of handleOpenIntent()
    _viewPager.setCurrentItem(navigationPosition);
    _foodsPagerAdapter.performSearch(searchQuery);
// end of additions

//removed
    //handleOpenIntent();
    //do more stuff (show ads etc.)
    Log.i("FoodActivityTest", "onCreate finished");
}
```